# How can I change the PID controller gains (Kp,Ki,Kd) in Arduino with potentiometers?

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I am using the PID library in Arduino in order to control the temperature of a laser. The thing is that I would like to be able to change the controller gains Kp, Ki and Kd from external potenciometers instead of doing it directly from the code.

As you may already know, in order to tune the PID you have to play a bit with these gains and this is why I would like to do it in real time instead of have to compile and charge the program in Arduino every time I want to change any of the values.

The way of declaring the PID in Arduino is:

```
PID myPID(&Input, &Output, &SetPoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, DIRECT);
```

What I undersand from there is that you can pass the value of the Input, Output and SetPoint by reference, which allows you to update the values at every loop. But Kp, Ki and Kd are constant values that are defined at the begining and they can't be changed while runing the program.

I would like to know if it is possible to update those values while the program is runing because otherwise I don't think I'll be able to tune this PID properly in less than one month.

Thanks.

Comment: let me google that for you: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PIDLibrarySetTunings

Comment: I feel a bit stupid now about this because I didn't think about that function, but thank you very much. Of course it works now.